# Post of almost a week old in the First Posts queue

Tags: support, review

Today, August 5, I got this review in the First Posts queue:

https://security.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/56514

The question was asked on July 30; almost a week ago. The last activity (edits, answers and comments) are dated July 31.

Note that it is *not* a review audit.

I'm wondering how a question that is days old, ends up in the First Posts queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the user's first post *now*. The first post review system picks up a user's first non-deleted post on the site. What happened is presumably that the user's first post was deleted, so his second post went into first post review.

I guess the intent is to route a user's first posts through review until one sticks — if post 1 is deleted, post 2 should be reviewed like post 1. But it also sometimes picks up extremely old posts from users who are by now well-established. I remember being told by Stack Exchange staff that this is by design, though I can't find the post/comment/chat message now.

Comment: @TildalWave The review hasn't been here for a week. Post 1 was deleted, and post 2 went into review *after the deletion*, long after it had been posted.

Comment: This would explain it. I'd be interested to know the reasoning behind it. As for the extremely old posts... only reason I can think of is when they're used as review audits, but that wasn't the case here.